# How to pass a component as prop to a child class and load it inside the child component with some more props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my parent class I have rendered a childclass compoment and passed another component to it as a prop and in the childclass component I want to load that component.

```
<EditRecordModal
    show={this.state.showEditModal}
    onHide={this.handleModalClose}
    handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
    dialogClassName="width-9x"
    modalTitle="Edit data"
    onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
    record={letter} 
    component={NewLetterEntryForm} >
</EditRecordModal>

export const EditRecordModal = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.onHide} dialogClassName={props.dialogClassName}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{props.modalTitle}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
              // here I want to load that props.component like this
             //  <NewLetterEntryForm showPageHead={false} mode="edit" record={props.record} onUpdate={props.onUpdate} />
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.handleModalClose}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

I tried this but it won't work....still

```
export const EditRecordModal = (props) => {
    const childComponent = props.component
    return (
        <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.onHide} dialogClassName={props.dialogClassName}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{props.modalTitle}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
                {React.Children.map(childComponent, (child, i) => {
                    console.log(child)
                    return child
                })}
            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.handleModalClose}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to pass child component as a props from the parent component. but if you want to use **React.Children** API, you should use like this:

```
 <EditRecordModal
    show={this.state.showEditModal}
    onHide={this.handleModalClose}
    handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
    dialogClassName="width-9x"
    modalTitle="Edit data"
    onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
    record={letter} 
    >
     <NewLetterEntryForm
       //some your props
     />
  </EditRecordModal >
```

and you also need to import your child component class before using it, add this line to the import area in your code: `import NewLetterEntryForm from 'yourPathTo NewLetterEntryForm'`